# What is the most optimized way to replace nan with 0 in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, fillna

Time to replace nan to 0 in a dataframe of 5 million rows using `df.fillna(0)` is about half an hour. Wondering if there's a more efficient way to replace the nan's with 0 in a more vectorized/efficient way.

Comment: 50 million rows is _so much_, I doubt there is any faster of a way.

Comment: 5 million. Sorry that was a typo.

Comment: How many columns are there?